# Prove the following holds for all Boolean algebras?

Tags: boolean-algebra

**For all x,y: (x ∨ y) ∧ x = x**

This is my attempt, I am just getting back to the question:

(x ∨ y) ∧ x

= x ∧ (x ∨ y)

= (x ∧ x) ∨ (x ∧ y)

= x ∨ (x ∧ y)

= (x ∨ x) ∧ (x ∨ y)

= x ∧ (x ∨ y)

So where am I going wrong here?

Comment: It is the *absorption* rule that must be applied. Only associativity, distributivity and/or commutativity will make run in loops only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not "going wrong"; $x \land (x \lor y)$ follows. Its truth table has the same result as $x$.From line 4 above, we have
$$\neg(\neg x) \lor (x \land y)$$

which is $\neg x \implies (x \land y)$.
Applying the absorption rule as in the comment gives
$$\neg x \implies (\neg x \land x \land y) $$

This is $x \lor F$ or $x$, as required.